# Understanding the proof of PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

I am currently watching the statistical machine learning course by uni tübingen on youtube, and I saw the the following slide. Could someone please explain to me how to get from step 2 to step 3, and maybe also, the dimension of matrix X and vector x_i here? Thank you very much!
The proof is like the following:

$\max\limits_{a \in \mathbb{R}^d, \Vert a \Vert = 1}  Var(\pi_a(X))$

->
$\max\limits_{a \in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum\limits^n_{i = 1} (\pi_a(x_i)^2)$ subject to $a^t a = 1$

->
$\max\limits_{a \in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum\limits^n_{i = 1} (a^t x_i)^2$ subject to $a^t a = 1$

-> (how does this step work?)

$\max\limits_{a \in \mathbb{R}^d} \Vert Xa \Vert ^2$ subject to $a^t a = 1$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UZqt.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: OK, I will type that then

Comment: And what exactly is $\pi_a$?

Comment: that's the projection on the a vector (a vector that has length 1)

Comment: Looks to me just like the definition of the projection on a vector with length 1 using that $a^\top a = 1$.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what she is trying to do here, but I am a bit confused about the dimension here. Could you please tell me what's the dimension of matrix X here? Is it (n, d) or (d, n)?

Comment: it seems that a:d,1 and X n,d

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I am still a bit confused, so in the third step, she multiplied $a^t$ and $x_i$ so if X is n, d, then $x_i$ should be a row vector that has the dimension 1, d. If a is d, 1, then $a^t$ should also be a row vector that has the dimension 1, d, how's that possible to multiply two row vectors together?

Comment: ok, let me summarize as an answer

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X: (n,d), $x_i$: (d,1), a: (d,1), $a^t$: (1,d)

$\left\lVert Xa\right\rVert^2$= $(Xa)^t (Xa)$ = $(a^t X^t )(Xa)$
= $a^t X^t Xa$
= ...
=$\sum\limits^n_{i = 1} (a^t x_i)^2$

The remaining part is the matrix multiplication.

$X^t=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &
x_2 &
\cdots &
x_n
\end{pmatrix}
$, $X=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^t \\
x_2^t \\
\vdots \\
x_n^t \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Keystep: $X^t X$ is the sum of columns of $X^t$ and rows of X.

$X^t X=\sum\limits^n_{i = 1} x_i x_i^t$

Comment: Sorry if you don't mind I have a follow up question about the notation, I just want to really make this clear. If X is a n, d matrix, and since i is just the dummy variable that indicates row index (because the value of it goes from 0 to n) so $x_i$ should be in this case a row vector, that is to say, has the dimension (1, d), right? So should there be $x_i^t$ instead of $x_i$?

Comment: you should note that if $x_i$ is a vector (d,1), then $x_i ^t$ is a vector (1, d) and $a^t x_i$ is (1, d) X (d, 1) is a number

Comment: for the matrix multiplication part, the link teach different types of matrix multiplication, you may refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX4C-JpTFgY&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=3

Comment: Well, may be I am not being clearly enough, but that's why asked this question in the first place, I already the dimensions don't match, and I don't think I have problem with matrix multiplication. So I think my confusion essentially boils down to a question about the notation here, that is, one, when uses the notation $x_i$, always indicates a column vector, despite the fact that it's actually a row in matrix X?

Comment: Anyways, thank you very much for your detailed answer, I think I will clear my confusion about the notation in a separate question.

Comment: n should be num of data points, d should be the number of features, so that it makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I get that part, but that's again, not what causes my confusion here. In matrix X, one row vector indicates a data point, whereas $x^i$ also indicate a data point but it's a column vector.

Comment: I know your points and confusion. It is better you do some searching of below concepts and summarize and ask
in a new question. I think it may be a deep question. In general, $R^n$ is a set of a tuple of numbers
when you view it as a set, and it contains only vectors when you view it as a vector space.
There is no concepts of column and row. But a m×n matrix can be view as a linear map from $R^n$ to $R^m$ in linear algebra.

Comment: It depens on the convention the authors used, to choose column or row. Here let say we choose $a\in R^d$ as a column vecotr, 
to compute the difference between a and another data points, the data points should be a row vector, but our convention used is column vector, 
so I think it should be transpose in X.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. :)